# I use fabric, but lots of with, so I want use python's decorator to make this code better

Tags: python, decorator, fabric

**base python code:**

```
for host in hosts:
    with settings(
                  host=host,
                  user=user,
                  password=passwd,`enter code here`
                  )：
       run('uname -a')
```

**I want to change like below:**

```
def take_with_out(host, user, password):
with settings(
              host=host,
              user=user,
              password=passwd):
    def dec(fn):
        def wrapper(*argv, **kwgs):
            fn(*argv, **kwgs)
        return wrapper
    return dec

@take_with_out(host, user, password)
def foo(command):
    run(command)

foo("uname -a")
```

The error message is to show me to type the host to make sure fabrice to ssh host, whereas the base code does not ask me the host, but the changed code should.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
class add_context(object):
    def __init__(self, host, user, password):
        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

    def __call__(self, function):
        def wrapped_function(*args,**kwargs):
            with settings(host=self.host, user=self.user, password=self.password):
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_function 

@add_context("localhost","unknow","password")
def foo(command):
    run(command)

foo("uname -a")
```